# Printing NSString from NSData & comparing HMAC hashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, hmac

I have a NSData which I hashed using HMAC algorithm. I wanted to print the resulted string & see how it looks but all the time I am getting (null) printed on the screen. I tried 2 methods but they did not work. Can someone suggest how to print the hashed data string? I wanted to compare the hash created this way with hash created on server which is JAVA. Now, JAVA returns a string object. How will that be compared with NSData created by objective C.

```
NSData *hmac = [aData HMACWithAlgorithm:kCCHmacAlgSHA1];
NSString *hmacStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[hmac bytes]];
NSString *hmacStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:hmac
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Hashed Data=%@ data2=%@",hmacStr,hmacStr1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that `HMACWithAlogorithm:` is returning the raw bytes that make up the digest rather than the bytes that make up the string UTF8 encoding of the digest.  This is based on an assumption that `HMACWithAlgorithm`: is using `CCHmac` from the `CommmonCrypto` library under the hood.

I think the following might do what you want, it will take the raw digest returned and convert it to a hex encoded NSString of the digest:

```
NSData *hmac = [aData HMACWithAlgorithm:kCCHmacAlgSHA1];

// Get a pointer to the raw bytes of the digest
unsigned char *digest = (unsigned char *)[hmac bytes];

// Convert the bytes to their hex representation
NSString *hmacStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                digest[0], digest[1], digest[2], digest[3], digest[4], digest[5], digest[6], digest[7],
                digest[8], digest[9], digest[10], digest[11], digest[12], digest[13], digest[14], digest[15],
                digest[16], digest[17], digest[18], digest[19]];      


NSLog(@"Hashed Data=%@",hmacStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second idea (hmacStr1) is fine.  If that string is null, then it casts doubt on your input data.

See what happens when you do this:

```
NSLog(@"about to hash %@, which is %d bytes long", aData, [aData length]);
NSData *hmac = [aData HMACWithAlgorithm:kCCHmacAlgSHA1];
NSLog(@"the hash result is %@, which is %d bytes long", hmac, [hmac length]);
```

Null data, right?  The fix needs to happen before the conversion to string.

Comment: This is the result for second print statement --> the hash result is <baa6624d d360bd36 d7befe85 999ece9a 6b493aec>, which is 20 bytes long

Comment: and then you log hmacStr1 and it's null?  Gosh sorry. I'm stumped.  just a thought:  are you getting the java hash from a server?  it will be NSData too, when it's the http result body.  NSData implements compare:, but anyway I'm surprised that the string does't work